Include font size specification to a command
I would like to include the specification of the font size (\huge \large \normalsize) in the key-value specification.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N  \l_hlov_tipoa_tl

\keys_define:nn { kvi_hlov }
  {
    tipoa .tl_set:N = \l_hlov_tipoa_tl,
    tipoa .initial:n = large,
    tipoa .default:n = large,
    tipoa .value_required:n = false,
    tipoa .usage = general,
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\hlov} { O{} m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_hlov} {#1}
    \centerline {\large {#2}}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\end{document}


Note that \large is not a command that takes an argument, it is a switch that changes the font size within the scope of the group. Therefore in this case \centerline {\large #2} would be correct, because \centerline creates a group. If used without a group then you can make a group youself by putting the braces around the command and the contents, i.e., {\large #2}.

You should show what you tried, but this is basic use of a c argument unrelated to keys
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N  \l_hlov_tipoa_tl

\keys_define:nn { kvi_hlov }
  {
    tipoa .tl_set:N = \l_hlov_tipoa_tl,
    tipoa .initial:n = large,
    tipoa .default:n = large,
    tipoa .value_required:n = false,
    tipoa .usage = general,
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\hlov} { O{} m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_hlov} {#1}
    \centerline {\use:c{\l_hlov_tipoa_tl} #2}% don't use \centerline in latex
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hlov{aaa}

\hlov[tipoa=tiny]{bbb}

\hlov[tipoa=huge]{ccc}

\end{document}



How does \use:c apply the command when the beginning \\ is not included ?  What could I use to center the text if I need to ?

@Bulldrive that is how \use:c is defined, it takes the name of a command and executes the command with that name (it 'adds the \' so to speak). This is essentially the same as what \csname \endcsname does in LaTeX2e.

A very convenient command, as adding the \\ was what I was planning to do.

Its description is not very revealing with the way you describe it though Expands the ⟨control sequence name⟩ until only characters remain, and then converts this into a control sequence.

And the example uses \use:c { \tl_use:N \l_my_tl }.

@Bulldrive this is all explained on the very first page of any expl3 tutorial,  \foo:c passes the result of \csname#1\endcsname to \foo:n. \tl_use:N is always optional since it does nothing

The example could be simplified if that is the case.  What should I use to center the text ?

@Bulldrive  \makebox[\textwidth]{xxx} or \centering xxxx or \begin{center}xxx\end{center} depending on the use case

Should I group the \use:c part, and write { \centering { \use:c {\tipoa_headlov} {#2} } \par } rather than  { \centering \use:c {\tipoa_headlov} {#2} \par }.  I use the outer braces for grouping the centering command.

\centering doesn't take an argument

I was referring to grouping the \use:c construct, not for use as argument to \centering.

well it's conventional (and clearer) to use {} but as always in tex if the argument is a single token the {} can be omitted in principle.
